# How do I trigger() an event on an element that uses delegate() to handle its events

Tags: jquery, delegates, triggers

I have a tab style navigation on a page. I want to display the appropriate tab if a tab identifier is passed in the URL when the page loads e.g. http://example.com/page.html#my-tab.

Currently the event handler for the A tag triggering a tab to display is delegated to it's parent :

```
$("nav.tabs").delegate("a", "click", function (e) {
    //trigger event
}
```

I am checking on page load for a HASH in the URL, checking to see if that corresponds to the HREF attribute of an A tag and then triggering that event but it's not working.

```
var tab = window.location.hash;

    if (tab != undefined) {
        console.log(tab)
        if ( $("a[href="+tab+"]" ).length > 0) {
            console.log(tab)
            $("a[href="+tab+"]").trigger("click");  
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works in Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome nor IE. The best way would to, instead of using an anonymous function, you can name it, and "fake" the call

```js
var $nav_tabs = $("nav.tabs");
$nav_tabs.delegate("a", "click", function clickme(e) {
 //trigger event
});

var tab = window.location.hash;
if (tab != undefined) {
    console.log(tab);
    if ((tab = $nav_tabs.find("a#" + tab)).length > 0) {
        console.log(tab);
        clickme.apply( $nav_tabs, [ { target: this } ]);   
    }
}
```